# open a HTML page using the ajax date

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax code and i am getting the data from serverside. Now i need to open the data as a popup or a seprate HTML.   I was trying the following code but its not helping.

```
                          <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
          $('#reschedule').click(function(){
              $.ajax({
                  type:'get',
                  url: "/schedule/"+id,
                  cache:false,
                  async:true,
                  data:id,
                  success: function(data) {
                      alert(data)
                      $("html").html($(data).find("html").html());

                  }

              })
          });



    </script>
```

so i need to open the responce as a seperate HTML popup window or a seperate page on the same tab. ANy Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `window.open` core javascript method.

**Example**

```
success: function(data) {
   window.open();
}
```

**More**

```
success: function (data) {
    var win=window.open('about:blank');
    with(win.document)
    {
      open();
      write(data);
      close();
    }
}
```

Also

```
var w = window.open();
$(w.document.body).html(data);
```

Comment: This is what exactly i was looking for. One more question i have. I need to use some jquerymodule (datetimepicker) on some of the fileds int the new page. How can i achive that?

Answer (score 0):

change

`$("html").html($(data).find("html").html());` to

`newWin = window.open("",'pageTitle','height=500,width=500');`

`newWin.document.write(data);`